# Is it possible to Always force terminate apps on windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is it possible to tell windows to **always** force terminate apps when I click exit button (X on right top) and most importantly when I click ***"Shutdown"*** or ***"Restart"***

I  already have the following but its not helping much. (Also windows updates keep reseting this back to 0 frequently. Thank you Windows)

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"AutoEndTasks"="1"
```

It is extremely annoying to wait gracefully stopping apps with 0 real benefit. Sometimes if you have unsaved changes apps like word even block the restart completely... (What is even more crazy is that they have **added an extra screen** whenever you try to exit word which asks you to save even if the file is completely **empty** but this is for another day.)

I love how Linux handles these scenarios: exit, restart, shutdown means Terminate no matter what !
I wish to have the same functionality on windows and not the useless gracefully whatever, waiting for gratefully kill is just a waste of time for me.

Also, dont tell me what if I really forgot to save smt etc. Never have I ever had a case in my life where that extra screen before the restart saved me anything. If I click restart while having unsaved changes, than yes I know I have unsaved changes and I do NOT want them to be saved.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a simple .bat file

```
shutdown.exe /p /f
```

Leave it on the desktop & use it instead of the regular shutdown procedure.

You can see the full list of options at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown

Comment: Alternatively disabling fast boot will do the same thing: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045548/

Comment: @Mokubai - My ageing desktop doesn't have fast boot. Thanks for the additional info.